Android MediaPlayer cant load or play anything? (No such file or directory)
I wanted to make a "custom notification sound", which you can change in the app's settings activity. The user could choose from a few default sounds, or choose a file themselves. To play these sound when showing the notification, I use MediaPlayer, however it does not load anything other than raw resource, no matter if I use internal/external paths, files, FileInputStream etc.
File picker result:
ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult> activityResult = new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult o) {
        if (o.getResultCode() == RESULT_OK && o.getData() != null) {
            Uri uri = o.getData().getData();
            if (uri == null || uri.getPath() == null) return;
            try {
                File file = new File(uri.getPath());
                InputStream stream = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
                String extension = file.getName().substring(file.getName().lastIndexOf(".")).trim();
                if (supportedFormats.contains(extension) && stream != null) {

                    // copying the file so it works even if the original is deleted
                    String filename = "custom_notif_sound" + extension;
                    File outFile = new File(getFilesDir(), filename);
                    outFile.createNewFile();
                    FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(stream, outFile);
                    stream.close();

                    setts.edit().putString("custom_notif_sound", filename)
                                .putInt("notif_sound", -1).apply(); 
                    // "notif_sound" is -1 when custom is selected; 0, 1, 2... when a default is selected
                    Log.d("qvkrimp", outFile.getAbsolutePath());
                } else {
                    Log.e("qvkrimp", "err2");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("qvkrimp", "err1", e);
            }
        }
    }
};

MediaPlayer initialisation (in BroadcastReceiver service):
final MediaPlayer mp;
MediaPlayer mp1;
if (setts.getInt("notif_sound", 0) == -1 && setts.getString("custom_notif_sound", null) != null) {
    try {
        FileInputStream stream = context.openFileInput(setts.getString("custom_notif_sound", null));
        mp1 = new MediaPlayer();
        mp1.setDataSource(stream.getFD());
        mp1.prepareAsync();
        stream.close();

        // I ALSO TRIED:
        File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), setts.getString("custom_notif_sound", null));
        FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(file);
        mp1 = new MediaPlayer();
        mp1.setDataSource(stream.getFD());
        stream.close();
        // but the result is the same
        // when using file.exists(), it returns true so the saving works fine

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("qvkrimp", "FILE NOT FOUND at custom notification " + setts.getString("custom_notif_sound", null));
        Log.e("qvkrimp", e.getMessage());
        mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.alertone);
    }
} else if (setts.getInt("notif_sound", 0) == 1) {
    mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.alerttwo);
} else { // setts.getInt("notif_sound", 0) == 0 but it works as a "default" if theres a problem with the custom
    mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.alertone);
}
mp = mp1;
mp1.release();
mp1 = null;

The error:
mediaserver                          E  Failed to open file 'android.resource://com.wotrox.qvkrfire/2131820545'. (No such file or directory)
com.android.systemui                 W  error loading sound for android.resource://com.wotrox.qvkrfire/2131820545
                                        java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
                                            at android.media.MediaPlayer._prepare(Native Method)
                                            at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(MediaPlayer.java:1347)
                                            at com.android.systemui.media.NotificationPlayer$CreationAndCompletionThread.run(go/retraceme 93beb7d7d00b428fa28f5dec001c038086b88bfc72edc63eb293d570b7834f39:91)

Manifest containt both READ_MEDIA_AUDIO and READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and they are allowed.
I looked around Stackoverflow and google for the past 2 days but I couldnt find anything about this.
I tried using Uri.parse, using file from external storage, but nothing seemed to work, I always get this exact same error.
Thanks for any help!
EDIT:
Running the same exact code, same exact file and method from an Activity works perfectly. Does MediaPlayer not work in services, only in activities?
